# mySQL - Combining result from rows depending on count in first row?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table that is filled with data from 2 other databases (textfile and htmltables)
The one thing that they have in common is the column order_number, thats why I have combined these into the same table. dr_* comes from a textfile and oi_* from a htmltable

```
Select * from data;
+--------------+-----------+----------+-----------+-------+
| order_number | dr_amount | dr_speed | oi_amount | oi_up |
+--------------+-----------+----------+-----------+-------+
|         9699 | 10000     | 26000    | NULL      | NULL  |
|         9699 | 20000     | 47619    | NULL      | NULL  |
|        10135 | 18000     | 12676    | NULL      | NULL  |
|         9979 | 25000     | 14286    | NULL      | NULL  |
|         9699 | NULL      | NULL     | 4800      | 4     |
|        10135 | NULL      | NULL     | 8700      | 2     |
|         9979 | NULL      | NULL     | 3000      | 8     |
+--------------+-----------+----------+-----------+-------+
```

First I haveto pick out order_number that are the only ones (with dr_amount) from the table using

```
select order_number, count(*) as c from data where oi_amount IS NOT NULL group by order_number having c<2;
+--------------+---+
| order_number | c |
+--------------+---+
|         9699 | 1 |
|         9979 | 1 |
+--------------+---+
```

This will remove the order_number's that have 9699 because it's in 2 rows && dr_amount=IS NOT NULL
(from my later handling I will not be able to match a specific row to another row if it is a duplicate-row, therefore I exclude all duplicates with dr_amount=IS NOT NULL)

Next I would like to produce this kind of output by combining order_number that have no duplicates (as dr_amount for same order_number) with the ones that has value with oi_*. Like this:

```
+--------------+-----------+----------+-----------+-------+
| order_number | dr_amount | dr_speed | oi_amount | oi_up |
+--------------+-----------+----------+-----------+-------+
|        10135 | 18000     | 12676    | 8700      | 2     |
|         9979 | 25000     | 14286    | 3000      | 8     |
+--------------+-----------+----------+-----------+-------+
```

As you can see, the order_number 9699 is sorted out, because of the non-duplicate sorting and 3rd and 6th row is merged, as well as 4th and 7th.

I was thinking of using the first filtering to get the order_number that are non-duplicates and pass it to a second select-query as the result within a where= but that gives me problem:

```
select order_number, dr_amount, dr_speed, oi_amount, oi_up from data where order_number=(select order_number, count(*) as c from data where oi_amount IS NOT NULL group by order_number having c<2);

Operand should contain 1 column(s)
```

I understand why that errors occur, but not how to solve it. When using the nested select that is required to sort out duplicates, it will return 2 columns (order_number and count(*) as c).
So how do I use the nested select so when I pass it to the real select it only contains 1 column?

Best regards
Niclas Gustafsson

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A subquery in that context cannot return two columns.  You also need `in` rather than `=` because it could return more than one row.  This may be what you are trying to do:

```
select order_number, dr_amount, dr_speed, oi_amount, oi_up
from data
where order_number in (select order_number
                       from data
                       where oi_amount IS NOT NULL
                       group by order_number
                       having count(*) < 2
                      ) and
      dr_amount is not null;
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the hint with moving the count(*) towards the end. That helped me put together the rest of it! Your suggested query didn't work out of the box. But this gave me the desired result:

```
select order_number, max(dr_amount) as dr_amount, max(oi_amount) as oi_amount from data where order_number IN (select order_number from data where oi_amount IS NOT NULL group by order_number having count(*)<2) group by order_number having dr_amount IS NOT NULL && oi_amount IS NOT NULL;
```

With this query, the rows will be merged as I wanted them to be :)
I removed dr_speed and oi_up because because they aren't really needed.

/Niclas